# reduce from PySpark RDD returns tuple

Tags: pyspark, rdd, reduce

```
data = data.withColumn('n', F.lit(10))
result = data.select('n').rdd.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
print(result)
```

Above code returns following output. But I was expecting single value which is the sum.

```
output:
(10,
 10,
 10,
 10,
 10,
 10,
 10,
 10,.....)
```

Comment: you can not add Row objects directly, try map before the reduce: data.select('n').rdd.map(lambda x: x.n).reduce(lambda x,y: x+y)

Comment: use `print(result[1])`

Comment: First `map` or `flatmap` then `reduce`